# UINavigationBar.Appearance.BarTintColor also influences my Tab bar background colour

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am writing an ios app in Xamarin and would like to achieve something similar to the theme of Facebook for ios, where the top navigation bar and the tab bar have different background colours.

I have this part in my AppDelegate.cs that sets the theme of the top bar to a nice green colour with white text.

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.BarTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(6, 144, 70); //bar background
UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes()
{
     TextColor = UIColor.White
});
UINavigationBar.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(250, 250, 250); //Tint color of button items
```

The problem is this also changes the colour of my Tab bar at the bottom of my page. At the moment I try to change it with this:

```
var tint = UIColor.FromRGB(6, 144, 70);
UITabBar.Appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
UITabBar.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(250, 250, 250);
```

But it does not seem to be working, the background of the tabs stays the same green colour.

[image]

Comment: Did you solved it? I have the same problem.

Comment: In the end, If I remembered correctly, we decided to go with the green color and two different icons, filled white and not filled, depending on if the tab was selected or not. Maybe try and implement a custom nav bar renderer, where you can set the colors?

Comment: I used svg image with SkiaSharp for displaying icons in custom footer bar.
You can refer to https://www.pshul.com/2018/01/25/xamarin-forms-using-svg-images-with-skiasharp/
For Tab page: https://github.com/thrive-now/BottomNavigationBarXF

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the background color of the entire tabbar.
use code

```
UITabBar. Appearance.BarTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(250, 250, 250);
```

If you just want to change the background color of selected item.

use code

```
        CGSize size = new CGSize( UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width/5.0,44 );

        //Background Color
        UITabBar.Appearance.SelectionIndicatorImage = imageWithColor(size);
        //Normal title Color
        UITabBarItem.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes { TextColor = UIColor.Blue }, UIControlState.Normal);
        //Selected title Color
        UITabBarItem.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes { TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB(6, 144, 70)}, UIControlState.Selected);

public UIImage imageWithColor(CGSize size)
    {
        CGRect rect = new CGRect(0, 0, size.Width, size.Height);
        UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(size);

        using (CGContext context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext())
        {
            context.SetFillColor(UIColor.White.CGColor);
            context.FillRect(rect);
        }

        UIImage image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

        return image;
    }
```

Color is my own random, you can change to your own needs.

Answer (score -1):

I used svg image with SkiaSharp for displaying icons in custom footer bar. You can change the color of icons.
You can refer to https://www.pshul.com/2018/01/25/xamarin-forms-using-svg-images-with-skiasharp/

For Tab page: https://github.com/thrive-now/BottomNavigationBarXF